# Mex File output Crashing after Building in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
#include <stdio.h> %%Initialization
#include <math.h>
#include "mex.h" 
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

 int first;
 int second; 
 int add,subtract,multiply
 first = (int)(mxGetPr(prhs[0])); 
 second = (int)(mxGetPr(prhs[1]));

 add= first+second;
 subtract=first-second;
 multiply=first*second;
 add=plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(0);
 subtract=plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(1);
 multiply=plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(2); 
 mxDestroyArray(add)
 mxDestroyArray(subtract)
 mxDestroyArray(multiply)
 return;
 }
```

> Crashing Every Time. It gets built up in the system workspace but crashing after Running(F9)

Comment: I don't think you should destroy those local `int` variables, only `mxArray`s allocated with `mxCreate*`. Freeing un`malloc`ed memory tends to cause problems.

Comment: What is this (and the next two lines) supposed to do `add=plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(0);`? That shouldn't even compile because you're trying to assign an `mxArray *` to an `int`. You need to inspect `nlhs` before indexing into `plhs` and don't `mxDestroyArray` things assigned to `plhs`, MATLAB will take care of memory management for those.

Comment: i am new to Mex Files, was not sure about that    add=plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleScalar(0);  assigns the output to the program.

Comment: You really need to become reasonably good at c, c++ coding first.

Comment: `c` and `c++` are great languages! But the right way to get started isn't through Matlab's mex stuff. All the MxArray * stuff even I find quite confusing at times, and I've been coding c/c++ for 15+ years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue what this code is supposed to do, but there are massive errors all over the place:

1. `(int)(mxGetPr(prhs[0]))` I can think of no situation where casting `double *` to an `int` makes any sense. We're taking the *memory address* of the array then potentially truncating it to 32 bits? This is almost certainly not what you want.
2. `subtract=plhs[1]` you can't assign an MXArray * to a an integer.
3. `mxDestroyArray(add)` You shouldn't call mxDestroyArray on an integer. Plus, you shouldn't call it on `plhs[0]` either because Matlab handles that.

Pointers in c and c++ are quite tricky. To write c or c++ code, understanding of pointers etc... needs to be nearly perfect. You really need to learn how to write basic programs, do basic coding in c/c++, understand types, understand pointers etc... before you go do stuff with Mex.

c/c++ are great languages! But I'd learn them elsewhere first.  Writing c/c++ code for Matlab mex is way too confusing/idiosyncratic an environment to learn the basics of c/c++.